# Angular4 uploading image in typescript on ie11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload an image to my web application in *Angular 4*.
I convert the input file with **readAsBinaryString()** and extract the ascii code with **btoa()** which I then pass to a backend service.
Everything works correctly on Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer 11.

To fix on ie11 I added the function **readAsBinaryString()** in the **polyfills.ts** :

```js
function str2ab(str) {
  let buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  let bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

if (!FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString) {
  FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString = function (fileData) {
    let binary = '';
    let pt = this;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      let bytes = str2ab(reader.result);
      let length = bytes.byteLength;
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
      }
      pt.content = binary;
      pt.onload();
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
  };
}
```

**image.component.html**

```html
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" (change)="fileChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="image" placeholder="Upload image">
```

**image.component.ts**

```js
  fileChange = function (evt) {
    let files = evt.target.files;
    let file = files[0];
    if (files && file) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => { // 'e' is undefined on ie11!
        let target = <FileReader>e.target;
        let result = target.result as string;
        this.byteArray = btoa(result);
      };
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  };
```

Currently with the polyfills works the function **readAsBinaryString()** on ie11, but in the function **reader.onload** gives the following error:
*Unable to get property 'target' of undefined or null reference*.

Answer (score -1):

You can check [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4163), and try to use the following code:

```
  fileChange = function (evt) {
    let files = evt.target.files;
    let file = files[0];
    if (files && file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event: Event) => {
        // event.target.result; // This is invalid
        console.log(reader.result); // This is valid
     };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  };
```